# Question about choosing name for Facebook fan page

Tags: seo, facebook, branding

I'm in process of creating new site which must be on domain `xyz-backgrounds.com` (assume that `xyzwallpapers.com`, `xyz-wallappers.com` and `xyzbackgrounds.com` are already used).

Search term which is widely used is `xyz wallpaper`.

Right now I need to create Facebook fan page where term `xyzwallpaper` is unused (mean I can register it).

Question is should I register it, since my domain is `xyz-backgrounds.com` or simply go for the `xyzbackgrounds` (brand awareness things etc).

Comment: I would try to build a brand around your name `XYZ Backgrounds`

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a marketing question, really.

But, this is my procedure if the domain I have is already locked (in your case: `xyz-backgrounds.com`) and the exact domain names are already in use as either usernames or vanity URLs on social media sites:

1. Check if *abbreviations* of your domain name might work. (i.e. `xyzbckgrnds`)
2. Check if *uppercase*/*lowercase variations* work. (i.e. `XYZ-Backgrounds`)
3. Check if *full URLs* work. (i.e. `xyz-backgrounds.com`, `www.xyz-backgrounds.com`)
4. Check if *marketing claim* works. (i.e. `best-backgrounds-ever`)
5. Check if I really really need this domain or if I can *register and brand another domain*. (i.e. `abc-backgrounds.com`)*
6. If none of these work: *be creative* (i.e. `sdnuorgkcab-zyx`) or *be uncreative* (`xyz-backgroundsdotcom`)

*this time doing my domain research first.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear enough. Both xyzwallpapers and xyzbackgrounds are available as usernames or vanity URLs. I just don't know which one to choose? xyzwallpapers have more searches than xyzbackgrounds, but my main domain is xyz-backgrounds.com and I'm affraid that some users will get confused if I choose xyzwallpaper (even if this is better option IMO).

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can register `xyzwallpapers` on Facebook fan page, for e.g. you have a website name (`hdwallpapers.com` or `hd-wallpapers.com`) and you have no choice on fb fan page to create `hd-wallpapers`, then in this situation you should register `hdwallpapers`, because search engines only focus on targeted keyword like your targeted keyword is (*hd wallpaper*) so you should register your targets words without abbreviations.